# HQL:Implicit Association joining not working

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I am using Hibernate 3.2.5 for my application.

I have a `Dept` table and an `Employees` table.

**Dept.java**

```
private int deptId;
private String deptName;
private Map empMap = new HashMap();
//Getters and Setters
```

**Employees.java**

```
private int empId;
private String empName;
private int deptId;
private int age;
private String sex;
private Dept dept;
//Getters and Setters
```

Association between these two:

```
<map name="empMap" inverse="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="DEPT_ID"></key>
      <map-key formula="EMP_ID" type="integer"></map-key>
      <one-to-many class="com.jdbc.Employees"/>
  </map>
```

When I try the below statement:

```
Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("from Dept dept where dept.empMap.empName = 'XYZ'");
```

I am getting the below exception:

`org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [dept0_.DEPT_ID.empMap] with element property reference [empName] [from com.jdbc.Dept dept where dept.empMap.empName = 'XYZ']`

Kindly let me know how to use the implicit join here. Reading the doc, I am not able to figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a collection like a property. You can do this instead:

```
from Dept dept inner join dept.empMap emp where emp.empName = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works fine. Need to clarify one thing before closing off the thread: I saw this query in the HQL section of Hibernate doc: `select cust.name.firstName from Customer as cust` In this query, if `name` is a `String` type property of `Customer` class then what is `firstName` ? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: `name` cannot be a `String`, i think that is a component type, i.e. another class.